# Powershell MS Teams 'New-Team' crashes

Tags: powershell

Exact error:

New-team -DisplayName 'my chosen display name' -owner 'my email address'

New-Team: One or more errors occurred.
At Line:1 char:1

New-Team -DisplayName 'my chosen display name' -owner 'my email address'

This causes my Powershell ISE to freeze and stop responding.
The error in itself is extremely vague, and google has not been any help so far.

I run PS5.1.19041.610 with the Teams PS Module version 1.1.6 (no-preview, stable release).

Yesterday it all seemed working just fine, today it doesn't..
Please help!

Thank you very much in advance.

[image: Here a screenshot of the actual error message!]

**EDIT: I've had this problem another time, and I think I've found the issue:
When you connect to Teams PS with Connect-microsoftTeams while being connected to Exchange Online with Connect-ExchangeOnline you are unable to create new teams which results in this error message. For future reference, this was the solution for me, disconnecting from Exchange Online**

Comment: Is that the full extent of the error message?

Comment: There was more, I've uploaded a screenshot!

Comment: Looks like very poor error handling design in `New-Team`, but you might be able to discover the inner exceptions (the errors that actually cause the problem) with: `$Error[0].Exception.Flatten().InnerExceptions |Format-List * -Force`, immediately after having reproduced the error

Comment: Message        : Cannot access a disposed object.
                 Object name: 'System.Net.Http.StringContent'.
ObjectName     : System.Net.Http.StringContent
Data           : {}
InnerException : 
TargetSite     : Void CheckDisposed()
StackTrace     :    at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.CheckDisposed()
                    at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.CopyToAsync(Stream stream, TransportContext context)
                    at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
HelpLink       : 
Source         : System.Net.Http
HResult        : -2146232798

Comment: That's the error message that pops up.

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out what the issue seems to be.. Can you help me with this error? :)

Comment: Looks like a bug in the `Teams` module, try using a previous version?

Comment: Thank you for your response! I've installed version 1.1.4 (the previous non-preview version) which resulted in a 'ToManyRequests' error code. I'm going to try one more version, I'll keep you updated

Comment: I'm no Teams admin, but I'm given to understand the Teams team is, ironically, better at keeping the preview versions stable, so you might actually be better off with the preview channel

Comment: You're totally right! The preview version worked for me. I went with version 1.1.10 for future reference.

Comment: Thank you soo much for your help!!